# Getting result in JS Web Scraping Cheerio impossible

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to get a result from this website: https://panel.undergroundromania.ro/profile.php?user=2041
I want to get the Nume: X variable and Prenume: Y variable, but they are in the same block and I can't just isolate the variables, how can I get two separate results with cheerio scraping in js?
I need something like:

```
var nume = $('body > div.c-wrapper > div > main > div > div > div > div.col-lg-3 > div > div.card-header.text-center > h4 > b').text();
var prenume= $('body > div.c-wrapper > div > main > div > div > div > div.col-lg-4 > div > div.card-header.text-center > h4 > b').text();
```

Comment: Why are you using such a complex selector when the element has the id `pills-ic`? If they change the layout, this brittle selector is likely to break. Do you have reason to believe the id will change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did it for me

```js
var nume = $('#pills-ic > b:nth-child(1)').nextSibling.data.substring(2);
var prenume= $('#pills-ic > b:nth-child(3)').nextSibling.data.substring(2);
```

Comment: One more thing, Do you know why I get this error? https://i.imgur.com/28JDA7G.png

Comment: If you can, please give me your discord ID so I can add you on discord and show you the code.

Comment: its farrrazz#0382